# Return a node and it's relationships and connected nodes, into a concrete class using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am trying out using Neo4j in .Net with Neo4jClient. I am trying to find the best way to populate the following concrete C# classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonData
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
    public List<string> Labels { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public Person Relative {get; set;}
    public string Relationship { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have the following basic graph model:

```
(p:Person{ id: 1, name: 'Fred', age: 42})-[r:PARENT_OF]->(c:Person{ id: 2, name: 'Sarah', age: 8})
```

Also with other relationship types, e.g. MARRIED_TO.

I currently have the following query, and I want to get a particular person node, and it's relations (i.e. the related person nodes and a string of what the relationship type is, which could be the relationship type or a value of the relationship), populating PersonData. I can currently easily populate Person, but I do not know how I can populate Relations.

```
var data = client.Cypher
            .Match("(p:Person)-[r*1..1]->(per:Person)")
            .Where((Person p) => p.Id == 3)
            .Return((p, per) => new PersonData
            {
                Person = p.As<Person>()
            })
            .Results;
```

Is this population of PersonData something I will have to do outside of the query, or can it be done in the return statement?

I also have the added problem that this query is returning the node with id 3 twice, and I do not know why.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with your classes - as long as you change from `List<Person>` to `IEnumerable`

```
var query = gc.Cypher.Match("(p:Person {Id:2})")
        .OptionalMatch("(p)-[r]->(p2:Person)")
        .With("p, {Relationship: type(r), Relative: p2} as relations")
        .Return((p, relations) => new PersonData
        {
            Person = p.As<Person>(),
            Relations = relations.CollectAs<Relation>()
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, was great to see you at Graph Connect :)